# Insert Index entry at specific position

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, vba

```
Selection.TypeText ("(" & Abbreviation & " placeholder )")

IndexEntryRange = ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry(Range:=Selection.Range, Entry:=Abbreviation, CrossReference:=Definition, CrossReferenceAutoText:="", BookmarkName:="", Bold:=False, Italic:=False)
```

Is it possible to insert `IndexEntryRange` at the `placeholder` position?

Comment: Do you mean insert the XE field before the "placeholder" text?

Comment: Hi Adam. No, I want the "placeholder" text to be substituted with the XE field which is the IndexEntryRange. As a final result the output in Word should be `(Abbreviation({ XE "Abbreviation" \t "Definition" })`. As such it should sit between the () brackets. Does that make it clear? Regards, Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly from the code you posted it might be easier to insert the index directly into position instead of replacing the placeholder text.

```
Selection.TypeText ("(" & Abbreviation)
IndexEntryRange = ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry(Range:=Selection.Range, Entry:=Abbreviation, CrossReference:=Definition, CrossReferenceAutoText:="", BookmarkName:="", Bold:=False, Italic:=False)

Selection.MoveEnd
Selection.MoveRight
Selection.TypeText (" )")
```